# Visualizing categorial data in a logistic regression plot

Tags: r, plot, regression, categorical-data

I am trying to create a plot for a logistic regression based on binary data as the dependent variable (direct leave = 0 or 1). The independent variables are continuous data (duration of danger cue), count data (time of danger cue presentation) and categorial data (treatment: sucrose or octopamine):

```
AnimalID       Time     Duration     Treatment       Daytime     DirectLeave
       1     1039.6          1.1       sucrose      mornings               1
       2     1116.5          7.6            OA      mornings               0
       3      359.9          2.4       sucrose     afternoon               0
       4      594.2         27.3            OA     afternoon               1
       5      951.4         10.5            OA      mornings               1
       6      612.4          3.8       sucrose     afternoon               0
```

So far, I was able to create two graphs (below) with one fitted line for the whole data set:

```
library(car)
data_animal <- read.table("DirLeave_DurSorted.txt",header=T)

# Plot for relationship between immediate leave of animal and the time of danger cue presentation

pufftimegraph<-glm(DirLea ~ Time , family=binomial(link=logit), data=data_animal)
summary(pufftimegraph)
Anova(pufftimegraph)
data_animal$fitted<-pufftimegraph$fitted

dummy<-(data_animal$Time)
dummy<-sort(dummy)
print(dummy)

plot(data_animal$DirLea~data_animal$Time, xlab ="Time of the presentation of the danger cue", ylab="Proportion of wasps leaving the patch")
lines(data_animal$Time,(1/(1+(1/exp(0.0011188*data_Maxi$Time+-0.0174130)))), col="black")

# Plot for relationship between immediate leave of animal and duration of danger cue

durgraph<-glm(DirLea ~ Dur , family=binomial(link=logit), data=data_animal)
summary(durgraph)
Anova(durgraph)
data_animal$fitteddur<-durgraph$fitted
print(data_animal$fitteddur)

plot(data_animal$DirLea~data_animal$Dur, xlab ="Duration of the danger cue [s]", ylab="Proportion of wasps leaving the patch")
lines(data_animal$Dur,(1/(1+(1/exp(0.15020*data_animal$Dur+-1.00618)))), col="black")
```

[image] [image]

However, the purpose of my study was to show the difference between both treatments. I know that I would need a slope and intercept value for both categories, i.e. sucrose and octopamine, but the `Anova()` only provides one value for the whole data set.
So, I'd like to create both graphs with two fitted lines: one for each treatment. Is it possible to do this and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

Your models here don't depend on the type of treatment, so you wouldn't get different curves out of the same model anyway. To compare between treatments, you'd have to include terms to the model that depend on the treatment, or fit models to subsets of your data.

It's also difficult to compare a model `DirLea ~ Time` against a model `DirLea ~ Dur` since they are not nested. The two models might be capturing different effects or the same effect depending on your experiment design and whether the two variables have any correlations

Let's say you started with a model that included all the things you're trying to compare:

```
model <- glm(DirLea ~ (Time + Dur)*treatment, 
             data=data_animal, family = binomial(link=logit))
```

You can construct arbitrary fitted lines by feeding artificial data to `predict`, and extract the relevant subset of your data with `subset`. Here, making a graph of data for the sucrose treatment and the danger cue fixed to some value:

```
sucrose.line <- expand.grid(treatment = "sucrose", 
                            Time = seq(100, 1200, length=50)
                            Dur=mean(animal_data$Dur))
sucrose.line$fitted <- predict(model, sucrose.line)
lines(fitted ~ Time, data = sucrose.line,
      xlab ="Time of the presentation of the danger cue",    
      ylab="Proportion of wasps leaving the patch")
```

Comment: Do I really need to include both time and duration into my model in order to construct arbitrary fitted lines? Anyways, the fitted line won't show up in the plot and I wonder why because I use the exact lines posted here.

Comment: Because the code posted above does not work (the fitted line does not appear in the plot), I used `ggplot(data_animal, aes(x = Time, y = DirLea, shape = Treat)) + geom_point() + 
     geom_smooth(method = "glm")` which resulted [in this graph](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38035375/ggplot_Treatment.jpg). Is it ok to use it even though it's not a linear regression?

Comment: I can't check whether the above works because you don't have enough of a dataset posted for me to actually run the code. As to the first question, it's not clear to me what statistical or analytic purpose you have for your fitted lines.

Comment: I testet the code above again and finally it works! However, the lines end and start [outside the graph](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38035375/Fitted_lines.jpg) which is rather strange. Does the artifical data also take into account that I am dealing with bionomial data here? I was able to tell ggplot that it should plot it according to the appropriate error distribution of the data: `+ geom_smooth(method = "glm", family="binomial", se=FALSE)` By the way, [this is the whole data set](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38035375/DirLeave_DurSorted.txt)

Comment: The reason as to why I need the fitted lines is because I want to vizualize the impact of the treatment on the behavior of the animal: Is it leaving or staying on the patch despite the fact that I presented a danger cue at a certain time? My hypothesis was that the animal will stay longer on the patch when being fed with octopamine in contrast to the control group which was only fed with a sucrose solution. Truth to be told, the result of my analyses is that the treatment did not manipulate the willingness of the wasps to stay longer on the patch or leave it earlier.